# MySQL - Row Deletion on one table does not update relationship at other table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 2 tables, one for the Employees and another for the Departments. A department can have multiple/different employees but one employee may only work in one Department. Their relationship is one to many.

**Table Creations:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS department(
    id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    street VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    employees_count INT(20) DEFAULT '0') 
ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
    id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    born INT(20) NOT NULL, 
    country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    department_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (department_name) REFERENCES department(name) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Table Insertions:**

```
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Alexandroupoli', 'Leoforos Dimokratias21');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Athens','Basilisis Sofias 111');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Patras','Smurnis 34');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Kalamata','Leoforos Fountas 241');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Heraklion','Leoforos Enetwn 132');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Thessaloniki','Karolou 45');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Xanthi','Agia Barbasa 68');
INSERT INTO department(name,street) VALUES ('Larisa','Hroon Polutexneiou 12');

INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Vaggelis','Michos','vagg7@gmail.com','1995','Greece','Athens');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('James','Gunn','james8@gmail.com','1970','USA','Athens');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('George','McMahon','george95@gmail.com','1978','Usa','Patras');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('John','Jones','john13@gmail.com','1992','England','Patras');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Marinos','Kuriakopoulos','marin_kur@gmail.com','1986','Greece','Alexandroupoli');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Dimitris','Nikolaou','dimitis8@yahoo.gr','1984','Greece','Larisa');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Soufiane','El Kaddouri','sofiane@yahoo.com','1974','France','Xanthi');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Maria','Apostolou','mariamaria1@gmail.com','1997','Greece','Larisa');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Ioannis','Marinou','ioannis_ap@yahoo.gr','1982','Greece','Kalamata');
INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,email,born,country,department_name) VALUES('Thanasis','Athanasiou','thanos89@gmail.com','1989','Cyprus','Heraklion');

UPDATE department SET employees_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE department.name = employee.department_name);
```

[image]

[image]

Upon creating the 2 tables and creating a foreign key constraint between them, when I delete a Department from the department table, every assosiated employee get deleted too, just as I need.

BUT, when I delete an employee from the employee table, the employees_count row in department does not change. For example, if I have 2 employees with a department_name = Athens, then upon deleting one of them, when I go to departments table, the employees_count remains equal to 2 instead of 1.

Same thing happens upon updating the department_name in employees table. If for one employee, I update his department_name from "Athens" to lets say "Patras", the department table remains unchanged.

So I was thinking, after I delete an employee, maybe also execute this command

```
UPDATE department SET employees_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE department.name = employee.department_name);
```

and that would certainly solve my issue.

BUT, is there a way for the employees_count column in department table to be **AUTOMATICALLY** assinged to the number of employees that work there instead of just being an integer field?
Is there a more practical way to solve this issue, instead of just adding the UPDATE command after each Deletion I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you don't need to store the department count in the table as a separate attribute; it's a value you can always find out through a query.

Also, deleting records can be very absolute. This is by no means best practice but I prefer to mark records as deleted (maybe with a time stamp). This is information, meta data I guess, that might be of interest. In this way all the employee information is retained. Food for thought.

Hope that was helpful.